# Error Setting Range with .Find

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to write a quick script that allows for automation in the generation of pipe networks for calculation of flow and other things. I have spent three days trying to get some code that I found for Range.Find working and no matter what example I find or what I try it just doesn't work.

I got rid of what I had been working on and went back to basics trying to get a simple instance of .find working.

Now I'm getting a 1004 run-time error, Application-defined or object-defined error.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim ContributingRuns As Range
Dim Structures As Range
Dim FirstStructure As String
Dim wsCollection As Sheets

'Set Range of Sheet That has Receiving Pipe Structures
Set Structures = Sheets("Pipes").Range("C5:C12")

With Structures
    Set ContributingRuns = .Find("S-1")

    If ContributingRuns Is Nothing Then
        Range("N1").Value = "None"
    Else
        Range("N1").Formula = "=M1"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

In column C there are a list of structures in the form of S-1, S-2,...,S-25 and so on.

The problem I have with this is right now the error stops the code at this line

`Set ContributingRuns = .Find("S-1")`

I cannot for the life of me figure out why its not working. All the examples look basically like the code I have provided except the option explicit.

Comment: Is this code in the sheet "Pipes"? It might be victim of re-entrance. Try with `Application.EnableEvents = False`.

Comment: @A.S.H A quick test shows that the code works fine when it isn't part of an event handler, so  you are probably right as to the source of the error. Perhaps you could post it as an answer.

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks, will do if OP confirms that the code is in the same worksheet they're writing into (which seems very likely though). :)

Comment: It is in the sheet pipes, so where would the solution you show go in the code?